# how to fetch dates from mysql tables and display these in fullcalender events

Tags: php, fullcalendar

I have a table in MySQL DB named as Leaves. I want to fetch those dates and display them dynamically on full calender how should i achieve this ?

For example, if a person has leave on 2016-08-09 and 2016-08-16 then these dates should show on fullcalender with the title of leaves....

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    events: {
        url: 'json-events-feed.php',
        type: 'POST', // Send post data
        error: function() {
            alert('There was an error while fetching events.');
        }
    }
});
});
```

This is i have done so far. I don't know what to do next i have fetch the dates from leaves_table in my `getleaves.php` file.

Comment: Please provide some data you fetch from `json-events-feed.php`

Comment: @SpazzMarticus i dont have any json-events-feed.php i am new to fullcalender this code is from the tutorial but that tutorial dint elaborate much about json_events_feed...i am unsure that what am i supposed to do in json_encode_feed i have fetched the dates from my getleaves.php

Comment: You need generate a JSON response from your data in this format http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/ so that fullCalender.js can understand and render your data correctly.